# An integral problem with the measure of a set in the integrand

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $f$ be a non-negative, measurable function on a $\sigma$-finite measure space $(X,\mathcal{B},\mu)$. Let $E\in\mathcal{B}$ and let
\begin{equation}
\phi_E(t)=\mu(\{x\in E: f(x)>t\}).
\end{equation}
Prove that
\begin{equation}
\int_E\log(1+f(x))\,\mathrm{d}\mu(x)=
\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1+t}\phi_E(t)\,\mathcal{d}t.
\end{equation}

Is Fubini's theorem a viable approach? How is the condition of $\sigma$-finiteness to be used?

Comment: Yes, Fubini's theorem is a viable approach. The $\sigma$-finiteness ensures the applicability of the theorem.